# How can I get the first letter of 3 words?

Tags: java, string

I am to make an application that will give the first letter of the inputted words in to caps. I am not getting any errors, I am just not getting any thing it keep running.

```
package threeletteracronym;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Matthew
 */
public class ThreeLetterAcronym {

    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter words.");
        s = keyboard.nextLine();       
        char a = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
        a = Character.toUpperCase(a);
        char b = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
        b = Character.toUpperCase(a);
        char c = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
        c = Character.toUpperCase(a);         

        System.out.println("Your new Acronym form " + s + " is " + a + b + c);       
    }

}
```

Comment: I assume this is not related to `javascript`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading and discarding the first line of input.

If you don't want to do this I suggest you drop this line `s = keyboard.nextLine();`

This is where a debugger would help if you step through your code.

Answer (score 0):

your code is not working because:
you need to remove the `keyboard.nextLine()` **AND** you made a copy/paste typo

`b = Character.toUpperCase(a);` and must be

```
b = Character.toUpperCase(b);
```

## Example:

```
System.out.println("Please enter words.");
// s = keyboard.nextLine();
char a = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
a = Character.toUpperCase(a);
char b = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
b = Character.toUpperCase(b); // uppercase of b and not a
char c = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
c = Character.toUpperCase(c); // uppercase of c and not a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test4 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter words.");
    char a = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
    a = Character.toUpperCase(a);
    char b = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
    b = Character.toUpperCase(a);
    char c = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
    c = Character.toUpperCase(a);
    System.out.println("Your new Acronym form is:" + a + b + c);
}
}
```

There are other ways like you can save each character to an array. Then you can display that array as your result.
Here it is by using string buffer:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test4 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter words: ");
    char text;
    StringBuffer sBuffer = new StringBuffer(5);
    for(int i=0; i < 3; i++) {
        text = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
        text = Character.toUpperCase(text);
        sBuffer = sBuffer.append(text);
    }
    System.out.println("Your new Acronym form is: " + sBuffer);
}
}
```